# Problem to start a nested for loop in C to iterate over arguments

Tags: c, string, for-loop

I am puzzled by the following code, which aims to iterate over all string arguments given and prints only the vowels.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1){
        printf("ERROR: You need one argument.\n");
        // this is how you abort your program
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    printf("Printing number of arguments %d\n", argc);

    for (i = 1; i <= argc; i++){
        for (j = 0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {

            char letter = argv[i][j];

            if(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z'){
                letter = letter + 32;
            }

            switch (letter) {
                case 'a': 
                    printf("'A'\n");
                    break;

                case 'e':
                    printf("'E'\n");
                    break;

                case 'i':
                    printf("'I'\n");
                    break;

                case 'o':
                    printf("'O'\n");
                    break;

                case 'u':
                    printf("'U'\n");
                    break;

                case 'y':
                    if (i > 2) {
                    // it's only sometimes Y
                    printf("'Y'\n");
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("%c is not a vowel\n", letter);
                }
            }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The program works but only prints the first argument I pass when calling ./ MARIANO ARGUELLO RIVERA

it prints only the results for the argument MARIANO and ignores all the others.

My guess so far (And I am still staring at the screen trying to find the solution), is in the second loop `argv[i][j] != '\0'`, when the program goes for the first argument, sees the **null byte**, at the end of the first string, and stops the iteration and does not go to the second, to process it.

Am I right?

Or should I take care of other detail in the code, so the iteration will be successfull?

Thanks

Comment: `for (j = 1;` ?? You got something against the 1st character in the argument? and.. `for (i = 1; i < argc;` **Move** `return 0;` **Outside** your loop `:)`

Comment: You are right, the original code was j = 0, this was a modified version of the trials I've done to solve that. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: 2-pairs of eyes are always better than one `:)`

Comment: Indeed! Thanks it solved the problem!. Another detail I missed. Now I am falling into segmentation fault problems, with my newest version, with the correction for the for(j=0) and the return 0; outside my loop. But I have to find out the solution, and I think that is something that requires another discussion

Comment: Did you fix `for (i = 1; i < argc;`? (not `<=`) Otherwise you try and derefernce the sentinel `NULL` at the end of the arguments with `argv[i][j]` -- Bad Juju...

Comment: Think of it this way: `char *argv[] = { "./getvowels", "MARIANO", "ARGUELLO", "RIVERA", NULL };` and `argc == 4`. What happens when you hit `argv[4][0]`? (classic off-by-one error), valid argument vector (argv) indexes are `0-3` but you don't care about the program name, so valid indexes are `1, 2, 3`. With `<=` you included `4` as an index (which is the index of the sentinel `NULL` at the end)

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thanks! that clarifies a lot! :)

Comment: Good deal, glad to help. Your code should be running now. Remember, you can always `#include <ctype.h>` and just do `int letter = tolower (argv[i][j]);` instead of the manual `if (letter >= 'A' ...)` Both are fine. Good luck with your coding. and.. If you are not preforming an actual output conversion, you can just use `puts ("'A'");` instead of `printf` (a good compiler will optimize that for you). When you need no `'\n'`, `fputs ("...", stdout);` will do `:)`

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Answer (score -1):

You did a fun mistake:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1){
        printf("ERROR: You need one argument.\n");
        // this is how you abort your program
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    printf("Printing number of arguments %d\n", argc);

    for (i = 1; i <= argc; i++){
        for (j = 0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {

            char letter = argv[i][j];

            if(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z'){
                letter = letter + 32;
            }

            switch (letter) {
                case 'a': 
                    printf("'A'\n");
                    break;

                case 'e':
                    printf("'E'\n");
                    break;

                case 'i':
                    printf("'I'\n");
                    break;

                case 'o':
                    printf("'O'\n");
                    break;

                case 'u':
                    printf("'U'\n");
                    break;

                case 'y':
                    if (i > 2) {
                    // it's only sometimes Y
                    printf("'Y'\n");
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("%c is not a vowel\n", letter);
                }
            }

    }
        return 0;
}
```

I simply made one correction. Please check now.,Its works now:)

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why that fixes it. Users shouldn't have to `diff` between the original and fixed code to figure that out.

Comment: As mentioned in comments, `return 0` should be placed outside of the for loop.